# Triggers & JSON!

Tags: trigger, json

I am trying to run a future method from a trigger. As the future method takes only primitives as parameters, i am serializing the Trigger.new to pass it to a future method. I am deserializing the JSON string into an object within the future method.
    //Trigger

```
trigger LeadUtlityTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    List retLead = LeadTriggerHandler.updateLeadRatingJSON(JSON.serialize(trigger.new));

    System.debug('retLead::'+retLead); // List with updated Rating__c 
    System.debug('Trigger new::'+trigger.new); //List with original Rating__c(null)
    }
```

inside the future method.

```
//Utility class
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHandler{
List leadReturn = new List();

@future  
 public static List updateLeadRatingJSON(String newLeadListJson){
 List newLeadList  = (List) JSON.deserialize(newLeadListJson,  List.class);
  for(Lead l : newLeadList) 
  {   
       l.Rating__c = 'UNK';
       leadReturn .add(l);
  }
  return leadReturn;
}

}
```

Everything works fine inside the future method, changing the Lead's fields,but nothing changes on the Trigger.new or Trigger.newMap, so i am ending up achieving nothing by using JSON's methods, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your code? It's hard to say what's happening without knowing a little more about what you're trying to do and what you have already put in place to do it.

Comment: any updating done by the future method can only be persisted using DML

Comment: Tried using update , but the update failed with an exception 'Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call:'.As it is a 'before insert' i do not have an ID yet..

Comment: It needs to be an after update trigger. You can use some logic to prevent the trigger firing for the same records again - see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are in a different context, you need to update your list of leads.
After this:

```
for(Lead l : newLeadList) {   
   l.Rating__c = 'UNK';
   leadReturn .add(l);
}
```

Call:

```
update leadReturn;
```

Don't return leadReturn, as you are in and `@future` context and there is nothing to return to.

Specifically, these calls won't show updated data:

```
System.debug('retLead::'+retLead); // List with updated Rating__c 
System.debug('Trigger new::'+trigger.new);
```

This is because the `@future` call has not happened yet and it's in a different context anyway.

And of course, there is no need to assign the result of your helper to a list variable for the same reason - it's not going to return anything. So change this:

```
List retLead = LeadTriggerHandler.updateLeadRatingJSON(JSON.serialize(trigger.new));
```

To this:

```
LeadTriggerHandler.updateLeadRatingJSON(JSON.serialize(trigger.new));
```

To prevent the trigger running on the same records, you can exclude them based on the freshly set data. Inside your trigger, gather the records that don't have a rating of 'UNK' and process only those.

```
Lead[] leadsToUpdate = new Lead[]{};
for(Lead l : Trigger.new) {   
    if (l.Rating__c == 'UNK'){
        continue;
    }
    l.Rating__c = 'UNK';
    leadsToUpdate.add(l);
}
LeadTriggerHandler.updateLeadRatingJSON(JSON.serialize(leadsToUpdate));
```

Then deserialize as before in your `@future` method.

Comment: Would not updating the list invoke a chain of actions, since it is called from a trigger? Can  i avoid doing any DML's from the future method?                         Also, i was returning the List only to debug the results.

Comment: Hmm, just realised you don't need an @future at all!! - i'll show you what your entire trigger should look like...

Comment: The whole purpose of making it a future method was to avoid hitting 'ConcurrentPerOrgApex Limit exceeded' on Web-Lead creation, which is happening more often in the recent past.

Comment: In that case, use my original answer and call `update` inside the `@future` method

Comment: You may want to do this trigger as an after update one and use a static variable to prevent reentry

Comment: The code i posted is only a sample code, there is lot more to it. I am not quite comfortable using a static variable since i have never taken that approach before and also it means changing a lot of code, unless that is the only choice. Can I use batch apex jobs to optimize the code? and not use the update's explicitly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23448/discussion-between-shalini-mendu-and-caspnz).